# $SO(n)$ is connected, alternative form

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups

I have the following exercise:

> Show that $SO(n)$ is connected, using the following outline: For the case $n = 1$, there is nothing to show, since a $1\times 1$ matrix with determinant one must be $[1]$. Assume, then, that $n \geq 2$. Let $e_1$ denote the unit vector with entries $(1,0,\ldots, 0)$ in $\mathbb R^n$. Given any unit vector $v\in\mathbb R^n$, show that there exists a continuous path $R(t)$ in $SO(n)$ with $R(O) = I$ and $R(1)v = e_1$. Now, show that any element $R$ of $SO(n)$ can be connected to a block-diagonal matrix of the form 
>   \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 &\\&R_1
> \end{pmatrix}
>   with $R_1\in SO(n- 1)$ and proceed by induction.

I have troubles only with the first part, i.e., Given any unit vector $v\in\mathbb R^n$, show that there exists a continuous path $R(t)$ in $SO(n)$ with $R(O) = I$ and $R(1)v = e_1$. Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Rotate in the plane spanned by $e_1$ and $v$.

Comment: Yes, but how can I express this rotation?

Answer (score 0):

The matrix 
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    cos\theta & -sin\theta  \\
    sin\theta & cos\theta  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
is in SO($2$) and means rotation.

For $3$-dimension, you first choose $\theta_1$ to rotate $(x,y,z)'$ to $(x,\sqrt {y^2+z^2},0)'$ continously:
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & cos\theta_1 & -sin\theta_1  \\
    0 & sin\theta_1 & cos\theta_1  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
\sqrt{y^2+z^2}\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This matrix A belongs to SO($3$).

And then similarly (called matrix B):
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
     cos\theta_2 & -sin\theta_2 & 0\\
     sin\theta_2 & cos\theta_2 & 0\\
     0 & 0 & 1\\
    \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
\sqrt{y^2+z^2}\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So, $R(0)=I$, $R(1/2)=A$, $R(1)=BA$